# Programming a chat bot with a easy programming Interpret interface

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I would like to do it (Probably it not necessary to do it) a console interface to make an implementation of a chat bot.
I would like my chat bot has 3 levels of “intelligence”.

**Level one**:  My chat bot is like a dictionary. You write something  like “If user say ‘Hello’, chatbot say ‘Hello’”. Or “if user say ‘How are you’, chatbot say ‘I´m fine, thank you’.
A example could be

```
>>If user say ‘Hello’then chatbot say ‘Hello’”.
>>Hello
Hello
>>if user say ‘How are you?’, chatbot say ‘I´m fine, thank you’.
>>How are you?
I´m fine, thank you
```

So is like a dictionary because the user build a LUT of phrases.

**Level two**: My chat bot has a database.

**Level three**: My chat bot ha a inference engines which can operates over the data base in order to make intelligence relations with the database

Does anyone knows something similar that has been done (I supposed it should be)?
Is there any specific language program to make these chat bots applications? 
Is there any open project to do it something like this (I supposed it should be)?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Using a database would probably just be a specific implementation of a look-up table approach. Levels 1 and 2 don't seem very distinct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your levels 1 and 2 are essentially the same and have already been accomplished through projects like [A.L.I.C.E.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_Linguistic_Internet_Computer_Entity). Solving level 3 is vastly more complicated, and is an active area of research in academia (i.e. there are no solutions currently).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try program-o? Version 2.01 which is the current one has an admin interface where you can teach stuff to your bot and create its personality. Worth a look and it's

https://github.com/Program-O/Program-O

Answer (score 0):

made originally by Stephan, cleaned up and made nice by me.Save it as a batch file. Input is a question basically, output, answer. If it does not know a question it asks you to give an appropriate response for it. Also it makes a text file in the same directory titled 'data' and it is simply formatted INPUT@OUTPUT so QUESTION@ANSWER

```
@echo off
color 3a
title AI
if not exist data.txt echo.>data.txt
:begin
set /p text="INPUT!: "
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=@" %%i in (data.txt) do (
  if /i "%text%"=="%%i" (
   echo OUTPUT!: %%j
   goto begin
  )
)
echo --- Unknown Input!
set /p answer=--- Please Specify An Output For '%text%'
echo %text%@%answer%>>data.txt
echo --- Output For '%text%' Saved!
goto begin
```