# Programming a chatbot with Perl

Tags: perl, chatbot

I'm studing Perl language. I think programming a chatbot would be a funny way of studing that language and learn it.

The [description of the chatbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174433/chatbot-programming-a-chat-bot-with-a-easy-programming-interpret-interface) I am interested in can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174433/chatbot-programming-a-chat-bot-with-a-easy-programming-interpret-interface).

Does anyone know any manual or website especially focused on programming chatbot in Perl language?

Answer (score 6):

See http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook - simple bot is described here: http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/IRC_Bots

[Documentation for Bot::BasicBot](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bot::BasicBot), which is a wrapper around POE::Component::IRC. http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/184416221

[Source of famous bot GumbyBrain](https://github.com/bingos/gumbybrain), which of course uses POE::Component::IRC and Megahal library. Megahal library uses Markov chains to reply to messages.

Don't use Net::IRC - it is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Chatbot::Eliza](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Chatbot-Eliza/) and [RiveScript](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RiveScript/) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Openclassifier on github is an opensource and has AI implementations, but its in Java though.

Still you can refer it to understand the implementations for chatbot. The reason I am referring this is, that it is a very simplified implementation, without any complex algorithms or datastructures.

You simply copypaste your data and the chatbot is operational with that knowledge. You can refer to my blog over this on below link:

http://miracleclassifier.blogspot.com/2018/02/artificial-intelligent-chatbot-you-can.html

Comment: This is a QA platform, so is expected you enter a question and receive answers. This seems not a question to me. Pleas clarify what are you asking for.

Comment: I replied to " Programming a chatbot with Perl".  I didn't ask any question. I told that openclassifier can be referred. I am not asking anything. Thx.

Comment: I apologize, i got a problem using UI and thought this was a question and not an answer.
I will remove the downvote as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some resources available for programming chatbots in Perl. Here are a few options:

Chatbot-Eliza-Perl: This is a simple implementation of the famous ELIZA chatbot in Perl. You can check out the code on GitHub and use it as a starting point for your own chatbot: https://github.com/ogdude/Chatbot-Eliza-Perl

AI::MegaHAL: This is a Perl module that provides an interface to the MegaHAL conversation engine. This module allows you to create your own chatbot by training it on a corpus of text data. You can find more information about this module on CPAN: https://metacpan.org/pod/AI::MegaHAL

Chatbot::Simple: This is another Perl module that provides a simple interface for creating chatbots. It allows you to define a set of rules for how your chatbot should respond to user input. You can find more information about this module on CPAN: https://metacpan.org/pod/Chatbot::Simple

Perl Maven: This site has a tutorial on how to create a simple chatbot in Perl using the Chatbot::Simple module: https://perlmaven.com/simple-chatbot-in-perl