# Need some info on IRC BOTS using PERL

Tags: perl, irc, bots

Does any one know of a good irc bot written in perl?

I just need a simple one that logs on to said channel, then replies things based on what the user says.

e.g.

The user:

```
<tgwizman> !time
```

The bot replies

```
<BlahBot> The time is 4:38:54 AM
```

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the part about module installation because that topic already has been discussed. You can simply undo it if you do not agree. Next time, please [open a seperate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for unrelated problems. – See the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: That's fine, and next time I will make a different question.

Comment: What have you tried writing so far and how did it work? This site is for questions relating to developing software, not software recommendation lists.

Comment: I'm not trying to write one, I'm more so looking for one to learn from. I would like to learn some perl, but I have recently lost interest in this topic, but I'll leave this page here for anyone else needing help referring to this topic, unless it would go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bot::BasicBot CPAN distribution](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Bot-BasicBot/) contains several example bots. [Projects Using POE](http://poe.perl.org/?Projects_Using_POE) page contains lists of POE-based IRC bots. See also answers here: [CHATBOT: Programming a chatbot with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271037/chatbot-programming-a-chatbot-with-perl)

Answer (score 3):

Last time I made an IRC bot I used [`AnyEvent::IRC::Client`](http://p3rl.org/AnyEvent%3a%3aIRC%3a%3aClient). The example there can be used to start developing your own bot.

Also [`Net::IRC`](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aIRC) page suggests some alternatives.